# Simple HTML DOM failed to get content from div

Tags: php, dom

i want to get content only inside div with id = table
from http://id.premierleague.com/in-id.html

i find http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm

try below code to get

```
require('simple_html_dom.php');

// Create DOM from URL or file
$html = file_get_html('http://id.premierleague.com/in-id.html');

$isi = $html->find("div[id=table]")->plaintext;

echo $isi;
```

but only see white screen and notice error

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/sports90.com/public_html/epl.php on line 43
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$isi = $html->find("div[id=table]", 0)->plaintext;
```

Comment: Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in /var/www/sports90.com/public_html/epl.php on line 43

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/sports90.com/public_html/epl.php on line 43

Comment: i changed my response, try it

Comment: Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/sports90.com/public_html/epl.php on line 44

Comment: it's unusual, you can show me what contain variable $html. 
print_r($html);

Comment: its too big, its always loading and make my laptop hang

Comment: ok, are you can show me print_r($html->find("div[id=table]"));

Comment: Array ( )
why i cant get the div with id = table,
i open the website its have that div

Comment: @PutraFajarHasanuddin Because this data uploaded from ajax

Comment: so, is there any how to get that content? thanks for try to help me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101416/discussion-between-leo-komarov-and-putra-fajar-hasanuddin).